# Bash: execute a string as if it was a script and pass parameters

Tags: bash

If I have a bash script stored in a file I can execute it as follows:

```bash
./path-to-script.sh param1 param2 param3
```

now if I have that same script stored in a variable:

```bash
script="$(cat ./path-to-script.sh)"
```

How can I execute it with those same parameters?

(For context - I'm running the script on a remote computer, and have to copy paste it into the command to send. I could echo it into a file in the remote computer and execute that, but if I can avoid touching the file system that would be better).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
bash -c "$script" my_script param1 param2 param3
```

`my_script` is gonna be the name of your script and appear in error messages. For example:

```
$ bash -c 'echo ${1bad_var}' my_script
my_script: line 1: ${1bad_var}: bad substitution
```